# Maximum of a sequence and convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, optimization

Consider a real sequence $(a_i)_{i \in \mathbb N}$ with $$0\leq a_i
\\
 \sum_{i=1}^Na_i \leq N$$ Suppose $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}a_i=0$$
Then is it true that

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^Na_i^2=0$$

Thanks and regards.

Comment: The second line $\sum_{i=1}^Na_i=N,$ if true for all $N,$ implies that every $a_i=1.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Oh you are right I must revise it. Thanks

Comment: I think you want to say $\sum _{i=1}^{N} \leq N$. In this case the conclusion is true.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could explain a bit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the hypothesis $\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i =N$ should be $\sum_{i=1}^{N}a_i \leq N$, since. otherwise, $a_n=1$ for all $n$. Taking this as hypothesis note that $\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i^{2} \leq \max \{a_i:1\leq i\leq N\} \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i$ (because $a_k^{2} \leq \max \{a_i:1\leq i\leq N\} a_k$ for each $k$). Divide by $N^{2}$ and let $N \to \infty$. Since  $\frac 1 {N^{2}} \max \{a_i:1\leq i\leq N\} \sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i \leq \frac 1 N \max \{a_i:1\leq i\leq N\} \to 0$ the proof is complete.